# TSQL: Fastest way to convert data_type and update it

Tags: performance, t-sql, database-performance

My database performance skills are not really good - I could not find any 'good' Google result, so I need your help.

I am trying to convert all columns of a table. All data in this table are datatype `varchar`.

I do have a reference table which has wrong data but correct meta data like Column_Name, Data_Type etc. ==> So I try to use the table with the correct metadata to convert the table with the correct data. As in the following example, the dynamic script wants to convert a column that should actually be `datetime`:

```
IF @Datatype IN ('datetime')
Begin
    set @sqlDate = ('
    Update dbo.'+@Table+' 
    SET '+@Column+' = TRY_CONVERT( datetime, '+@Column+', 105)

    Alter Table dbo.'+@Table+'
    Alter Column '+@Column+' datetime;
    ')

    exec (@sqlDate);    

End
```

So my goal is to convert a Table like this :

```
+----------------+----------------+
| Col1 (varchar) | Col2 (varchar) |
+----------------+----------------+
| '01.01.2000'   | '124.5'        |
+----------------+----------------+
```

To this:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+
|     Col1(datetime)      | Col2 (float) |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| jjjj-mm-tt hh:mi:ss.mmm |        124.5 |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

(based on the correct metadata table)

Do you think its better to first convert data into #TempTable and Update the original Column via the pre-converted #TempTable? Any better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That looks wide open to injection. But it looks like you're trying to convert `datetime` columns to a `datetime`; that is completely pointless. Show us, with sample data and expected results, what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: What's the point of this code? Unless the column is a `datetime` or `sql_variant`, the converted value is converted *back* to the original type. If that's a string, it becomes a string again using the "local' format (whatever that is). The server will have to convert the values *again*

Comment: On the other hand, updating 15M rows, and then changing the type of the column will always take a while - the server has to convert all those strings to datetime *again* and validate them. It would make more sense to add a *new* `datetime` column, store the converted values there, rename both old and new columns and finally delete the old one

Comment: Sorry ... I ve updated my post ... hope you get my point now

Comment: But  `'124.5'` isn't a date, so why are you trying to change *that* to a `datetime`?

Comment: Why do you care about performance? This should be a one-time thing anyway - who cares if it takes 30 minutes or 5 hours? I would, however, go with Panagiotis Kanavos's advice - Add new columns to the table with the correct data types, populate them with the `try_convert` / `try_cast` results, drop the old columns and rename the new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save is this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
(
    DateTimeColumn varchar(50),
    FloatColumn varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Sample(DateTimeColumn, FloatColumn) VALUES ('01.01.2000', '124.5');
```

Then - Alter the table to add the columns with the correct data type.

```
ALTER TABLE Sample
    ADD AsDateTime DateTime,
        AsFloat float;
```

Populate the new columns:

```
UPDATE Sample
SET AsDateTime =  TRY_CONVERT(datetime, DateTimeColumn, 105),
    AsFloat = TRY_CAST(FloatColumn AS float);
```

At this point, you should pause and check if you really did get correct values.
Once the new columns data is verified, you can delete the old columns

```
ALTER TABLE Sample
    DROP COLUMN DateTimeColumn;

ALTER TABLE Sample    
    DROP COLUMN FloatColumn;
```

and rename the new columns:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Sample.AsDateTime', 'DateTimeColumn', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Sample.AsFloat', 'FloatColumn', 'COLUMN';
```

A quick select to verify the change:

```
SELECT DateTimeColumn, FloatColumn
FROM Sample;
```

Results:

```
DateTimeColumn          FloatColumn
2000-01-01 00:00:00     124.5
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)